# Google CSE (Chrome Extension) - Parsing JSON Data with JS

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to query my Google custom search engine in my Chrome extension, and parse the returned JSON.

My goal is to utilize the current tab URL in my request to the CSE, so I tried to adapt the sample code from the [Image Search example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/tutorials/getstarted.zip) that Google provides, since it is somewhat similar.

The code uses an XMLHTTPRequest to communicate with the custom search server:

```
 var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
 x.open('GET', searchUrl);

 // The Google image search API responds with JSON, so let Chrome parse it.
 x.responseType = 'json';
 x.onload = function() {

 // Parse and process the response from Google Image Search.
 var response = x.response;
 alert(response);
 if (!response || !response.responseData || !response.responseData.results ||
    response.responseData.results.length === 0) {
  errorCallback('No response from Google Image search!');
  return;
}
```

Whenever I try to view the response var, it is undefined. I tried changing the 
`var response = x.responseText;`, but was unsuccessful.

My question is, what is the correct way to use javascript to parse and process the JSON data, while abiding by the Chrome Extension guidelines?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Blaine

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you didn't add the permission request to the manifest. Try setting it like [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr). When it comes to parsing, use JSON.parse(x.response). Also make sure you call x.send() (I can't see it in your code) after the end of onload callback.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @P0lip, thanks for the response. I added "https://www.googleapis.com/" to my manifest permissions, and will look back into JSON.parse(x.response).

I do have a x.send() at the end of the function, sorry for not including.

Answer (score 0):

See the error inside your request...
[image]

Comment: [The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited. We encourage you to use the Custom Search API, which now supports image search.](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v2/jsondevguide#sending-a-basic-query)

Comment: thanks for posting. In my code, I reference the Custom Search API, and not the Image Search API.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if(xhr.status === 200) {
            var responseText = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            // Do what you want with responseText
        }
    }
};
x.open('GET', searchUrl);
```